# Get third element of JSON document via JQ and BASH/SHELL

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, jq, aws-cli

i have some instances in AWS. I want to get these applications via special tag.

My `AWS CLI` command, via tag `IAMOWNER`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Owner,Values=IAMOWNER" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]]" --region us-west-2
```

Output of this command:

```
[
    [
        [
            "i-d21eei21e912e0e91",
            "192.168.1.203",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-10"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-ddaswed1e12415155",
            "192.168.1.210",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-103"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-dass1241211agh354",
            "192.168.1.202",
            [
                "myindexapplication-DEV-53"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-2143214251assaa11",
            "192.168.1.211",
            [
                "myserviceapplication-DEV-52"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-d2112421521assas1",
            "192.168.1.207",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-10"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-sadas11112424111a",
            "192.168.1.196",
            [
                "myapplication-DEV-106"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The question. How can i get elements for example of `mycentralapplication` via `jq` library in `bash` or `shell` ?
For example, i have to receive only `mycentralapplication` in output

```
[
    [
        [
            "i-d21eei21e912e0e91",
            "192.168.1.203",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-10"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-ddaswed1e12415155",
            "192.168.1.210",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-103"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "i-d2112421521assas1",
            "192.168.1.207",
            [
                "mycentralapplication-DEV-10"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

How can i do this ?

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" "Name=tag:Owner,Values=IAMOWNER" --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,PrivateIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value[]]" --region us-west-2 | jq -r "mycentralapplication"
```

In this case, i am returning error. The question, is it possible to resolve this task via `jq` ? Or I have to use `grep`, etc ... ?

Comment: So you mean "get elements where a leaf matches x" and not at all what the question title says?

Comment: I want to receive all parameters of instances with name mycentralapplication from list of instances, that i have received @tripleee

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify, probably change the title if it doesn't actually reflect what you want. Your comment seems to be repeating rather than clarifying what you already said.

Comment: And, is there a reason you don't include your criterion in the filter expression in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jq script:

```
aws ... | jq 'map(select(.[][][]?|contains("mycentralapplication")))'
```

This selects all nested arrays elements containing the string `mycentralapplication`

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mycentralapplication"   "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running"   |  jq -r   ".Reservations[] | .Instances[] | .NetworkInterfaces[] | .PrivateIpAddresses[] | .PrivateIpAddress "
```

Take a look at the full output of

`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=mycentralapplication"`

you will see how i am pulling the values.